# Groupby + transform + lambda-функция от двух переменных

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, lambda, transform

Есть DataFrame c несколькими уровнями группирующих ключей вида (`группа`, `подгруппа уровня 1`, `подгруппа уровня 2` и тд.). Есть столбец `значения 1` и `значения 2`. Необходимо создать столбец, являющийся результатом деления накопленной суммы `значения 1` на накопленную сумму `значения 2`, причем, накопление этиx двух сумм происходит внутри, например, `подгруппы уровня 2`.

Я попытался выполнить конструкцию вида:

```
df['Cumsum_div']=df.groupby(by='Группа')[['значение 1','значение 2']].transform(lambda x,y: x.cumsum()/y.cumsum())
```

Код генерации примерных данных:

```
df_old = pd.DataFrame({'Группа':['A','A','B','B'],'Значение 1': [1, 3,3,1], 'Значение 2': [2, 5,3,4]})
```

Пример желаемого результата:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'Группа':['A','A','B','B'], 'Значение 1': [1, 3,3,1], 'Значение 2': [2, 5,3,4], 'Cumsum_div': [0.5, 4/7, 1, 4/7]})
```

Результат должен быть следующего вида (внутри одной группы):

```
Группа Значение 1  Значений 2   Cumsum_div   
     А          1           2          0.5
     А          3           5          0.57142857.....
     B          3           3          1
     B          1           4          0.57142857.....
```

Comment: Вы можете привести в вопросе код для создания небольшого синтетического датасета и датасет, который вы хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: Дополнил, благодарю

Comment: мне кажется это не очень удачный пример входных данных - решение не требует группировки: `df_old[col1].cumsum() / df_old[col2].cumsum()`

Comment: Групп по столбцу "Группа", будет много. Следовательно, накапливать суммы надо с учетом группировки по "Группе". Поправил пример

Comment: Причем, желательно воспользоваться максимально базовым языком, чтобы можно было позже перевести это действие в SQL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [46]: x = df_old.groupby("Группа").apply(lambda x: x["Значение 1"].cumsum() / x["Значение 2"].cumsum())

In [47]: df_old["Cumsum_div"] = x.to_numpy()

In [48]: df_old
Out[48]:
  Группа  Значение 1  Значение 2  Cumsum_div
0      A           1           2    0.500000
1      A           3           5    0.571429
2      B           3           3    1.000000
3      B           1           4    0.571429
```